# How to make data on chart not duplicate, in PHP?

Tags: php, highcharts

I've made bar chart use "highchart". It works but part of my data on the chart has been duplicated. For more details see this picture

[image: duplicate data graph]

My script like this

[image: script]

Comment: try a SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: Too many reasons to flag this question, but can only choose one :| Go read [ask] please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add "DISTINCT" directive in your first SQL query to get only unique records from the table:

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT penempatan FROM peserta";
```

Also, avoid using mysql_* functions in your PHP code, as they are deprecated and will not work in latest PHP versions. Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.